# facing issues to start appium inspector session getting error - /wd/hub/session 500

Tags: android-studio, session, appium, inspector, appium-desktop

1.I am stuck in installing .apk file in virtual device of android studio
2.I did  set desired capabilities in inspector session and while start session facing some errors again and again

Comment: could you add your capabilities?

Comment: Can you please share the github link to your script so that the issue can be debugged & identified for resolution?

Comment: Yes i have added that desired capabilities

Comment: Could you attach to the question the capabilities that you are using?

Comment: {
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:deviceName": "Android Emulator",
  "appium:app": apk path
}

this capabilities i have added in session... and there is apk location path i have provide in place of apk path